# Range of $a$ in damping

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> For the differential equation $\displaystyle a\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+5\frac{dx}{dt}+5x=0,$ where $a>0$

> Represent supercritical damping, Then range of $a$ as

What i try ::  Here we have campare with  $\displaystyle A\frac{dx^2}{dt^2}+b\frac{dx}{dt}+C=0$

Then $A=a,B=5,C=5$

So  here $D=B^2-4AC=25-5a$

Can anyone please tell me here $D>0$ or $D<0$ for supercritical damping.

Please help me , Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an equation of the form:
$$Ax''+Bx'+Cx=0$$
dividing through by $A$ gives:
$$x''+\frac BAx'+\frac CAx=0$$
now let:
$$2\zeta\omega_n=\frac BA\qquad\omega_n^2=\frac CA$$
which gives:
$$x''+2\zeta\omega_nx'+\omega_n^2x=0$$
now solve this equation using the standard method and you will see that $\zeta$ is the damping ratio. Critically damped is defined as $\zeta=1$ so in your case you want:
$$\zeta>1\Rightarrow \boxed{\frac{B}{2\sqrt{AC}}>1}$$
now rearrange and work it out for this specific situation

Answer (score 1):

You should have $D=B^2-4AC=25-\color{red}{20}a$

The characteristic equation is $$a\lambda^2+5\lambda+5=0$$ which has the solutions $$\lambda_1=\frac{-5+\sqrt{25-20a}}{2a},\quad\lambda_2=\frac{-5-\sqrt{25-20a}}{2a}$$

and there are three cases to consider which depend on $D$.

$i)$ $D<0$: underdamping, complex roots

$ii)$ $D=0$: critical damping, repeated real roots

$i)$ $D>0$: overdamping, distinct real roots